# Higher reputation Area 51 committers not showing site icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I've recently noticed that some users with significant reputation who have committed to Area 51 proposals do not have the usual site icons in their user details. This is despite the fact that the accounts tab in their Area 51 profiles shows that they have 200+ reputation on at least one other site which is what I understood the threshold to be.

I noticed this first with 3 users on the [Libraries proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12432?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top) but checked a few other proposals and found similar cases on [Writing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top), [Databases](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top), and [Personal Productivity](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top).

Here are some examples (at the time of posting all appeared on the first "most recent" page of commitments for the referenced proposals).

- Writing: [John Gardeniers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/21920?tab=accounts#tab-top) with 12k across sites ([10,691 on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/9278/john-gardeniers))
- Databases: [Vivek Bernard](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/22000?tab=accounts#tab-top) with 861 across sites ([710 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242888/vivek-bernard))
- Productivity: [David Antaramian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/22085?tab=accounts#tab-top) with 576 across sites ([425 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259573/david-antaramian))
- Libraries: [Nicholas Piasecki](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/22052?tab=accounts#tab-top) with 4599 across sites ([4,478 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32187/nicholas-piasecki))

**Update:** All of the users I saw with missing icons now appear to have the site icons in their user details block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the users mentioned in the question created and associated their accounts within the last day or so.

We just a fixed a couple bugs in which a) new users' multi-site flair didn't show up correctly until they gained additional rep/badges on one of their associated sites, and b) multi-site flair wasn't being reliably updated, particularly for beta site stats.

We just re-synced each user's multi-site flair with their associated account info, which fixed the flair issues for users mentioned in your question (and hopefully any other problematic flairs as well).